# Git shell not enabled?

Tags: shell, git

I'm trying to install git server. When I set default shell for my git user to /usr/bin/git-shell I get an error upon login as git.

```
fatal: Interactive git shell is not enabled.
hint: ~/git-shell-commands should exist and have read and execute access.
```

Ssh key based access work, permissions are set correctly.

Google search does not show anything regarding this error.

I also used this method in past installations and no such error was shown. Also I looked at working server if it has some extra files or config but no such thing.

System spec:

- Gentoo linux (latest)
- Git 1.7.5.3

/etc/passwd line:

```
git:x:1002:1004::/home/git:/usr/bin/git-shell
```

Comment: `git-shell` is a restricted shell to be used for push/pull functionality only (i.e. `git push`, `git fetch` and `git pull`). It's not meant to be interactive, so you should not login in an interactive shell. You can make it somewhat interactive by adding a `git-shell-commands` directory in the user's home and symlinking some binaries inside. But it's very limited (there's no binary for `cd`, for example), so a better alternative is to login as `root` or a `sudo`able user and do `sudo -u git -s` to get a full `bash` shell under the `git` user.

Answer (score 19):

I found this after running `locate git-shell-commands`

> cat /usr/share/doc/git-1.7.4.4/contrib/git-shell-commands/README
>
> Sample programs callable through git-shell.  Place a directory named
>   'git-shell-commands' in the home directory of a user whose shell is
>   git-shell.  Then anyone logging in as that user will be able to run
>   executables in the 'git-shell-commands' directory.
>
> Provided commands:
>
> help: Prints out the names of available commands.  When run
>   interactively, git-shell will automatically run 'help' on startup,
>   provided it exists.
>
> list: Displays any bare repository whose name ends with ".git" under
>   user's home directory.  No other git repositories are visible,
>   although they might be clonable through git-shell.  'list' is designed
>   to minimize the number of calls to git that must be made in finding
>   available repositories; if your setup has additional repositories that
>   should be user-discoverable, you may wish to modify 'list'
>   accordingly.

So I ran the following commands as root:

```
cp /usr/share/doc/git-1.7.4.4/contrib/git-shell-commands /home/git -R
chown git:developers /home/git/git-shell-commands/ -R
chmod +x /home/git/git-shell-commands/help
chmod +x /home/git/git-shell-commands/list
exit
```

I was then able to run the following as the `git` user:

```
[me@svn ~]$ su git
Password:
Run 'help' for help, or 'exit' to leave.  Available commands:
list
git> help
Run 'help' for help, or 'exit' to leave.  Available commands:
list
git> list
git> exit
```

Now I don't see what good help and list are, but the login worked. :)

Comment: there would have to be bare repositories in the users' home directories for "list" to do anything (as per the readme)

Answer (score 6):

i just had to do `# mkdir ~git/git-shell-commands` then `su git` worked for `git 1.8.1.5-r1`

Comment: Yeah, it works. Now you're in the git shell. Then what? It's completely useless for interaction unless you symlink some binaries inside `git-shell-commands` folder. I think it's more useful to skip all that and do `sudo -u git -s` so that you get a full `bash` shell with access to all binaries. You also stay in the current directory.

Answer (score 3):

If you [look at the code](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/PATCH-shell-Rewrite-documentation-and-improve-error-message-td5445842.html) which triggers that error message (which [seems to have been different](http://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/g7aiu/sorry_gitshell_my_bad/) in older versions of Git):

```
if (access(COMMAND_DIR, R_OK | X_OK) == -1) {
  die("Interactive git shell is not enabled.\n"
     "hint: ~/" COMMAND_DIR " should exist "
     "and have read and execute access.");
```

this should be a right issue on the git-shell directory.

> The user must have read and execute permissions to the directory in order to execute the
>   programs in it.

Comment: ... just as it says in the error message, in fact.  (-:

Comment: @JdeBP: sorry ;) @Peter and I suppose you do have `~/git-shell-commands` with the right permissions?

Answer (score 1):

I'm late to the party, but as stated [in the git docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-shell), all you have to do is run the following command on the remote host:

```
chsh -s $(command -v git-shell) <user>
```

Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

**Apply these two commands it will resolve this issue:**

To enable git-shell for your_git_user:

usermod -s /usr/bin/git-shell your_git_user

To change owner of your_git_user directory recursively:

chown -R your_git_user:your_users_group /home/your_git_user

**You may add git shell commands using below command:**

cp /usr/share/doc/git-1.8.3.1/contrib/git-shell-commands/ /home/your_git_user/git-shell-commands -R